# References on the history of electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

I am looking for complete and trustable references on the history of electromagnetism. Does anyone have some good recommendations?

Comment: Related: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16041/is-there-a-concise-but-detailed-history-of-electricity

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ideally I would prefer some references more related to theoretical physics (up to gauge theories) instead of the engineering aspect of electricity.

Comment: Edmund Whittaker, A history of the theories of Aether and Electricity, 2 volumes, Harper & brothers, NY 1951.

Comment: Thank you very much!